# Trying to make a server in Java that sends an image to my Android device using sockets

Tags: java, android, image, sockets

I'm trying to send an image using a Java server to my Android device but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

The code for the server is:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception 
{ 


  ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789); 
  Image image = null;




  while(true) { 

       Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept(); 

       BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream())); 

       ObjectOutputStream  outToClient = new ObjectOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream()); 



       File f = new File("/resources/image.png");
       image = ImageIO.read(f);

       outToClient.writeObject( new ImageIcon(""+image) );


    } 
} 


}
```

I think the problem is in the server because the Android app works with another server

client:

```
BufferedReader inFromUser =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 

DataInputStream in;

BufferedInputStream buf;

DataInputStream mod ; 

Socket sc = new Socket(myIP,48000);

DataInputStream infromServer = new DataInputStream(sc.getInputStream());

mod =  infromServer;

Bitmap mPhotoPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(modifiedSentence);

imagen.setImageBitmap((mPhotoPicture));
```

Comment: can you compare the data sent by the two servers? (yours and the other one). Is there a reason to not use some higher transport layer? say, http?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other server is probably sending the raw image data (not an ImageIcon serialized object).  It looks like BitmapFactory expects the image's raw bytes. Try writing the raw bytes out to your socket:

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
int size = (int)f.length();
byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
fis = new FileInputStream( f );
int read = fis.read( bytes );

connectionSocket.getOutputStream().write( bytes );
connectionSocket.getOutputStream().flush();
```

Obviously, you'll need to add some error detection and handling to make this robust.

Comment: I'm new to this... i put the code and it dosen't seen to work

Comment: Doesn't work how? Doesn't compile or doesn't function properly?

Comment: it doesn't function properly or mayby i'm doing some thing wrong. if you could guide me a litle

Comment: Is there an Exception of any type on the client side decoding the image? Or is it just not getting the data? Try adding some debugging or sniffing the packets (tcpdump/wireshark) to ensure the data is getting from server to client.

Comment: i have been working in a new server and client... i get the same problem trying to use your idea but where do you put the data from the file to the bytes???

Comment: `int read = fis.read( bytes );` is the line that reads the file off the disk.